# Algorithm to solve n variable problem with range

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

During Software designing our team come across the following problem: we have linear equation with n variables with each variable have positive permissible range or allowed range.

In This Problem the constant a_i are the number of items person wants to be bought of type x_i which has minimum value of purchase l_i and maximum value of purchase r_i and now, buyer know about this ranges that why he smartly ask that is this possible within value b. So now we have to choose one solution if possible and give the invoice accordingly.

So in math form,

```
 a1x1+a2x2+....+anxn = b
 known parameters:
 a1,a2,...,an and b
 unknown parameter x1,x2,....,xn
 but we know that 
 x1 belongs to range [l1,r1]
 x2 belongs to range [l2,r2]
 .
 .
 .
 xn belongs to range [ln,rn]
 0<li<ri
 ai>0
 b>0
```

and we need to find values of all xi in above equation(may be float or integer but must be range). I need to solve this problem as soon as possible.
Example :

```
  Let n be 5
  And equation is
  10*x_1+15*x_2+10*x_3+11*x_4+17*x_5=2365
   And allowed ranges are 
   For 
   X_1 [30,60]
   X_2 [20,40]
   X_3 [20,80]
   X_4 [50,120]
   X_5 [10,140]
  So one of the solution will be
  For 
  X_1 =40
  X_2 =36
  X_3 =34
  X_4 =60
  X_5 =25
```

Want to find only one solution.
I need solution in bigO(nlogn)
Or nearly linear as possible as.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are saying $x_i$ are real values and you want to find *all* values of $x_i$. Did you really mean that or did you want any feasible solution that meets the constraints? There are an infinite number of real values in any range $(a,b)$.

Comment: @vvgirl I just want to find one solution which is according to my constraint

Comment: You may also want to look up the bounded variable simplex method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of finding a feasible solution to a linear program. By introducing extra variables $s_i$ and $e_i$ so that

$$x_i-e_i=l_i\\x_i+s_i=r_i\\e_i,s_i\ge0$$

all of the constraints are now equations and every variable must be positive.

One way to find a feasible solution is to use the 2-phase simplex method. This involves introducing even more variables so that every equation becomes trivial to solve initially.

\begin{align}&\text{minimize}&y_0+y_1+\dots+y_n&=z\\&\text{subject to}&a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n+y_0&=b\\&&x_1-e_1+y_1&=l_1\\&&x_2-e_2+y_2&=l_2\\&&\vdots\quad\\&&x_n-e_n+y_n&=l_n\\&&x_1+s_1&=r_1\\&&x_2+s_2&=r_2\\&&\vdots~\\&&x_n+s_n&=r_n\\&&x_i,y_i,e_i,s_i&\ge0\end{align}

Note that $y_i$ are essentially the errors of the first $n+1$ equations. If you get $z=0$ in the end, then you have a feasible solution. Otherwise no such solution exists. With some more details, you can even find all of the solutions where $z=0$.

There are many tutorials online you can find on how to solve the above problem using the simplex method as well as plenty of software for solving such problems, such as excel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$\Phi= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\,x_k-b\right)^2$$ and minimize $\Phi$ with $n$ bound constraints $l_k \leq x_k \leq r_k$.

If you want to get rid of the constraints, define
$$x_k=l_k+\frac{r_k-l_k }{1+e^{-y_k} }$$

As @vvgiri  commented, you can face an infinite number of solutions (may be less if one or more bound constraints are active). For your example, the first I obtained is
$$\left\{34,\frac{85}{4},\frac{83}{4},85,\frac{2255}{68}\right\}$$

Comment: What is y_k in above equation and can you give more details about above idea?

Comment: $y_k$ is the new unbounded variable for the problem. It can vary between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. But the first approach is rather simple.

Comment: In above how I can find x_i's ? By substituting each range value of x_it's?

Comment: Just want to find one solution any one and I am done

Comment: how you obtained the solution can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in some cases there may not exist a solution. For instance, if $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i r_i < b$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i l_i > b$, no solution will be available. This corresponds to the situations in which taking the upper bound for each variable is not enough to get $b$, or in which taking the lower bound for each variable already exceeds $b$.

Anyway, if $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i r_i \ge b$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i l_i \leq b$, you can just solve this as linear programming problem... The set of restrictions will be
\begin{align*}
a_1x_1 + \cdots +a_n x_n & = b &\\
x_i & \ge l_i \quad i=1, \cdots , n\\
x_i & \leq r_i \quad i=1, \cdots, n
\end{align*}

The objective function is not very relevant here. You can, for instance, minimize $x_1$, yielding the solution with the smallest value for $x_1$, or any other criteria you see fit. In the example you presented, one gets

$$x_1 = 30, x_2=20, x_3=20, x_4=50, x_5 = 1015/17.$$

Note: Since you just want an admissible solution, you can implement a very simple scheme. Initialise all variables $x_i = l_i$ and compute $a \cdot x$. If $a\cdot x > b$ the problem is impossible; If $a\cdot x = b$, you got the solution; If $a\cdot x < b$ start setting $x_i = r_i$ until $a \cdot x$ exceeds b; when that happens, just tune the last $x_i$ so that the equality is attained.